# Does a capacitor respond faster than a battery?

Tags: decoupling-capacitor, battery-chemistry

I grew up with the rule of thumb that you should always put a 47 uF tantalum capacitor wherever power enters a PCB. Perhaps that's a little dated now. I then recently built a battery powered circuit and followed this rule.

Is there any point including the capacitor?  Would you decouple a good alkaline battery?  My understanding is that the electrical power is derived from a [redox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redox) reaction within it's metals or their oxides. Wikipedia says:-

> Redox reactions can occur relatively slowly, as in the formation of rust, or much more rapidly, as in the case of burning fuel.

Rusting and burning (even exploding) fuel doesn't seem to operate at GHz speeds. A capacitor can. Chemicals have mass and volume. And they're gooey. So is a capacitor faster at responding to demand than a chemical battery?

Comment: I agree with @DKNguyen (as usual). The ESR of the capacitor is probably a lot lower than the battery so it will definitely suppress voltage ripple. I have designed several production PCB's  that ran on alkaline batteries. I usually used something like 10 or 22uF, not necessarily as large as 47uF. But I believe it is a good practice to have at least 10uF on any PCB unless it is just a switch or just an LED or something like that. There is also inductance of wires leading from battery to board to consider.

Comment: @mkeith That's a good point. A battery with a mass and volume thousands of times that of a capacitor will still have an ESR that is only comparable to that capacitor.

Comment: Putting a large capacitor wherever power enters a PCB is not dated, but using a tantalum part is. Speaking of gooey exploding things.

Comment: The cap is sane, not sure I would use a tant however! Tants across stiff power rails have some 'interestingly exciting' failure modes that for me usually make them inferior to a modern electrolytic.

Comment: @mkeith Hmm, leads...  I tend to twist the power leads together for ease of management. That's probably adding to the inductance, no?

Comment: @PaulUszak maybe not the twisting per-se, but if you allow extra length, the length adds some inductance. Just another reason to keep an electrolytic or tantalum cap on the PCB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if a capacitor is faster but if I had to guess, I would guess that the electrostatic mechanism in a capacitor is a lot faster than the chemical mechanism in a battery.

But even if batteries were just as fast as capacitors, you would still use capacitors. One thing the capacitor has is a lot less inductance than the battery. Furthermore, there are usually a lot more components that need a low inductance power source in a circuit there are batteries, and it is a lot easier to place a capacitor right next to each component (thus minimizing wiring/trace inductance) than it is to give each one its own battery.