# Why are PC motherboards covered with many large capacitors?

Tags: decoupling-capacitor

This is a contemporary Xeon motherboard:

[image: motherboard]

When I was growing up, the wisdom was that you placed a 47uF capacitor where the power leads attached to a digital PCB.  Now, this seems to have been [updated](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/521385/does-a-capacitor-respond-faster-than-a-battery#comment1340166_521385) to just a 10uF as circuitry has become more efficient.

Why is this motherboard covered in bulky electrolytic capacitors?  I can't read their capacitances, but there are at least 30 of them. I can't see a reason why given that such boards operate at GHz speeds.

Comment: `I can't read their capacitances` ... what's printed on them?

Comment: @jsotola Err, I can't read them...

Comment: @jsotola Neither can I.

Comment: @PaulUszak ... I understand now, you did not take that picture ... it is a requirement of this site that you add a reference to the source of any included material ... please edit it into your question

Comment: @jsotola Exactly what I was about to say. :)

Comment: How many watts does your motherboard pull?   And then what happens when there is a spike in demand?  The processor is dynamically messing with its clock or power to minimize power consumption.   Being ghz implies that your spikes are going to have heavy current changes, yes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I drew boxes around all of the things that are clearly (even at this very low resolution) DC to DC converters:

[image]

As you can see, nearly all of the electrolytics are associated with a DC-DC converter. The reason for this is a that these converters typically require a largish capacitor at both the input and output (or perhaps several). There are so many DCDC converters because motherboards take in +12V and then locally convert it into the many voltages required by the CPU, memory, I/O ports, etc.

By the way, these are likely much larger than 10uF, which can now be done in 1.6mm long ceramic capacitor. If you zoomed in to the board surface, you'd see that many (perhaps most) of those white boxes are actually silkscreen around tiny ceramic capacitors.

Comment: There's what looks to be another switching converter to the right of the PCI slot. I don't see its inductor, though; it could be a small chip inductor for low power (might just be powering the fan header?), or perhaps it's a linear regulator. I definitely see some of those capacitors near a big transistor though.

Comment: There are also specific requirements for some IO ports. For example USB host ports require at least 100 µF to handle the inrush current when a device is plugged in.

Comment: And most of the other electrolytics are next to what are almost certainly linear regulators.

Answer (score 4):

Several reasons.

- There are many different power rails for CPU, RAM, ports. Something like 3.3V, 2.5V, 1.8V, 1.2V, 0.8V...
- Fast variation of current which means that capacitors must be placed close to the loads, to reduce impedance, so several capacitors are placed for the same voltage supply. There are also several local power supplies which must have capacitors on the input and output. Current drawn on CPU is so high (tens of amperes) that a multiphase power supply is needed, with each phase having several capacitors.
- Electrolytic capacitors are low cost but not as good (series resistance) as tantalum for example, so more capacitors are necessary.

There are also hundreds of smaller SMD capacitors (maybe underside?) for high frequency decoupling.

Answer (score 3):

It's about local storage of energy.

Think of it as a gas station, vs if everyone had to drive all the way to the refinery's huge storage, it would be impractical. And the more cars that fill up at a certain station, the more gas would be logical to store there.

In today's digital circuit you will find capacitors next to IC's, and a motherboard is no exception. There's a major difference though compared to the gas station analogy, it's not impractical but mandatory for a digital circuit to operate, or IC's otherwise would reset due to voltage drops because of the power latency through long traces back to the voltage source. And the higher demand, the more local storage is needed.

In the motherboard you see there's a higher concentration of caps around the CPU, since it's the main power consumer and there's a lot of power regulation there.

Answer (score 3):

A 1000ft overview: GHz speeds are not a big concern. The big concern is that the CPU cores can ramp up from idle dissipation (a couple W total) to full dissipation (50-100W) in a matter of microseconds. This requires low AC impedances in the 0.01MHz-1MHz region, and those caps provide this low impedance.

To understand what the demands placed on the supplies are: Most bench lab power supplies - even expensive ones- have a couple orders of magnitude too high output impedance to directly power the cores of modern CPUs and even chipsets. Local power regulation and serious decoupling is needed close to the load.

Comment: Not only that, but modern CPUs run on quite low voltages, which means they can easily suck down 100 *amps* instantaneous.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things have changed over the years.

1. While the performance per watt of microprocessors has improved, the performance per dollar has improved faster. So the total power consumption of high end microprocessors at full CPU load has increased massively. A NMOS 6502 apparently used half a watt and the CMOS variants even less, modern CPUs can use well over a hundred watts.
2. As part of the drive for efficiency, voltages have moved ever lower and currents ever higher. A modern CPU might need over a hundred amps at less than a volt for it's core supply. And it needs a bunch of different voltages.

A standard PC power supply supplies 12V, 5V and 3.3V. Lower voltages must be supplied from "point of load" buck converters for multiple reasons. The first being there is no standard for PC power supplies supplying voltages less than 3.3V and the second being that with such low voltages and high currents volt drop becomes a major issue.

Generally you want capacitance on both the input and the output of a voltage converter. Particularly a swith-mode converter

Low power systems, like phones or Raspberry Pis may rely entirely on ceramic capacitors for their point of load converters, but as the power levels increase more capacitance is needed to maintain acceptable ripple and electrolytic capacitors become the more economical option.